# Google App Engine query optimization

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine datastore that could have several million records in it and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do a query where I need get records back that match several Strings.

For example, say I have the following Model:

String name
String level
Int score

I need to return all the records for a given "level" that also match a list of "names".  There might be only 1 or 2 names in the name list, but there could be 100.

It's basically a list of high scores ("score") for players ("name") for a given level ("level").  I want to find all the scores for a given "level" for a list of players by "name" to build a high score list that include just your friends.

I could just loop over the list of "names" and do a query for each their high scores for that level, but I don't know if this is the best way.  In SQL I could construct a single (complex) query to do this.

Given the size of the datastore, I want to make sure I'm not wasting time running python code that should be done by the query or vise-versa.

The "level" needs to be a String, not an Int since they are not numbered levesl but rather level names, but I don't know if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`IN` filter operator](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Overview) to match property against a list of values (user names):

```
scores = Scores.all().filter('level ==', level).filter('user IN', user_list)
```

Note that under the hood this performs as much queries as there are users in `user_list`.

Answer (score 0):

```
players = Player.all().filter('level =', level).order('score')  

names = [name1, name2, name3, ...]

players = [p for p in players if p.name in names]

for player in players:
    print name, print score
```

is this what you want?
...or am i simplifying too much?

Comment: My worry is that the Player.all().filter(...) query might return several hundred thousand records and that could be a strain on python to then shift through them.  Obviously the work as to be done by someone, but the database engine might be better optimized to do that (like mysql often is rather than php).  I just didn't see a way to offload that work to the GAE database and there might not be given how it works.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not do that in one pass.

You will have to either query the friends for the level one by one

or

make a friends score entity for each level. Each time the score changes check which friends list he belongs to and update all their lists. Then its just a matter or retrieving that list.

the first one will be slow and the second costly unless optimized.

Comment: Your second option is an interesting idea.  I might see what that one looks like.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not correct. You can use the `IN` filter operator to perform a query against a list of values.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the IN operator, you can use that. Just make sure that if you have over 30 friends you need to make two queries as the sub-queries are limited to 30.